# An Apollo x female Harry Potter fan fiction

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

In this, female Harry adopted Teddy after the war and refers to him as her kid. She is summoned to the Olympus council meeting to read books about her life.

Comment: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9122984/1/The-Aftermath matches the premise. Not certain on the council bit.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fan-fiction-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 1):

As a 90% match, ["The Aftermath"](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/9122984/1/The-Aftermath) by Umecchi has Apollo meet a pregnant Adelaide Potter who has adopted her godson Teddy, and immediately delivers triplets, the father being Fred Weasley, who has died in the interim. However, I haven't found anything yet where she's brought to the council to read books about her life.